# Submiting form without refreshing a page

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have multiple divs , show/hide on button click div , inside one of these divs I have a table and to filter this table to search a specific user I use a PHP code and a submit form the problem is after submitting the form the page refreshes and the 1st div appears although the request worked and when I revisit the table div the filtering appears. I used this code to stop the refresh but the form is not being submitted:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {

  $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'admin.php',
      data: $('#myform').serialize(),
      success: function () {
        alert('table is filtered');
      }
    });

  });

});
</script>
```

and here is my form:

```
<div class="in5 n5" id="users">
    <br>
    <form method="post" action="" id="myform" >
        <table style="width:25%;height: 13%;table-layout: fixed;  font-family: signika;background-color:white;color:white;border-bottom:1px solid white;">
            <tr>
                <td width="30%" style="text-align:center;">
                    <button style="width:100%;height: 100%;border:0; font-size: 20px;font-family: signika;background: transparent;">Show all</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="height:100%;width: 100%;"> 
                        <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Search user" style="height:100%;width: 70%; font-size: 20px;" >
                        <input value="Search" id="search"  name="search" type="submit" style="width:30%; height: 100%; float: right; background-color: gray; color:white; font-size: 20px; "> 
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table style="width:100%;height:10%; background-color: white; font-size: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; table-layout: fixed;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:3%;">ID</td>
                <td style="width:10%;">Username</td>
                <td style="width:10%;">Email</td>
                <td style="width:10%;">First name</td>
                <td style="width:10%;">Last name</td>
                <td style="width:5%;">Gender</td>
                <td style="width:10%;">Birthday</td>
                <td style="width:8%;">Country</td>
                <td style="width:7%;">City</td>
                <td style="width:10%;">Bio</td>
                <td style="width:5%;">Access</td>
                <td style="width:7%;">Picture</td>
                <td style="width:5%;">Ban user</td>
            </tr>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
            <tr >
                <td style="width:3%; overflow: hidden;"  title="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
                    <input style="border:0;background: transparent; font-size: 20px;" readonly="readonly" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
                </td>
                <td style="width:10%; overflow: hidden;" title="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                <td style="width:10%; overflow: hidden;" title="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>"><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                <td style="width:10%; overflow: hidden;"title="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>"><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
                <td style="width:10%; overflow: hidden;"title="<?php echo $row[5]; ?>"><?php echo $row[5]; ?></td>
                <td style="width:5%; overflow: hidden;"title="<?php echo $row[6]; ?>"><?php echo $row[6]; ?></td>
                <td style="width:10%; overflow: hidden;"title="<?php echo $row[7]; ?>"><?php echo $row[7]; ?></td>
                <td style="width:8%; overflow: hidden;"title="<?php echo $row[8]; ?>"><?php echo $row[8]; ?></td>
                <td style="width:7%; overflow: hidden;"title="<?php echo $row[9]; ?>"><?php echo $row[9]; ?></td>
                <td style="width:10%; overflow: hidden;"title="<?php echo $row[11]; ?>"><?php echo $row[11]; ?></td>
                <td style="width:5%; overflow: hidden;">
                    <?php if($row['12']=="moderate"){ ?>
                        <a href="lock.php?id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
                            <img class="img2" src="icons/access.png" ></a> 
                    <?php } else{ ?> 
                        <a href="access.php?id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
                            <img class="img2" src="icons/locked.png" >
                    </a> <?php } ?> 
                </td>
                <td style="width:7%; overflow: hidden;">
                    <a href="#image" title="See profile picture"   class="cover" >
                        <?php  if($row[10]==""){ ?> 
                            <img class="cimg2 " src="images/profile.png"> <?php 
                        } else { ?>
                            <img class="cimg2 " src="img/<?php echo  $row[10] ?>" >
                        <?php }?> 
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td style="width:5%; overflow: hidden;">
                    <a  title="Delete user" href="deleteuser.php?id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"  style="border:0;background: transparent;">
                        <img src="icons/ban.png"></a></td>
            </tr> 
            <?php endwhile;?>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and the PHP code:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
  $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
  // search in all table columns
  // using concat mysql function
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `r` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, `username`,`email`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
  $search_result = filterTable($query);
}
else {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `r`";
  $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
  $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "x");
  $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  return $filter_Result;
}
```

the problem is on submit the page is not refreshing and the alert appears but also the table is not filtering.

Comment: If only half of a page is loading that is a clear indicator of a PHP error so use [PHP error logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) to see what's going on.

Comment: You're missing result returning in your MySQLi, you've sent the query ok but once the server has the query you've given it no data about how you want it to [return the data](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).Hence improper data is being given back to you.

Comment: Why are you using jquery 1.9.1 when the current version 1 jquery is 1.11.1, upgrade by changing a few characters on your jQuey reference!

Comment: changing the version did not work , also the result are returning just fine if the preventDeafult() did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use on click not on submit and input type button

```
    $('#myform').on('click', function (e) {
```

Comment: i tried this also  $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) { is not working either but id of the div (#users) is appearing in the title like if the div is open but really it's not .

Comment: But @Rishi: Where is submit button? I am unable to find it man.

Comment: Technically you're not submitting the form, you're merely sending it to the server with Ajax so the jQuery never reaches the `on('submit'`, as suggested, replace with `on('click'`. @yasserh

Comment: the submit button is in the 8th line of the form and the name ="search" @Nana partykar

Comment: @Nana Partykar: search for submit you will see `<input value="Search" id="search"  name="search" type="submit" style="width:30%; height: 100%; float: right; background-color: gray; color:white; font-size: 20px; "> `

Comment: @Rishi but i am using the submit button to trigger the search in the php code , if(isset$_POST['search'])

Comment: Yes it will work, 
        `data: $('#myform').serialize(),` is sending post in ajax so just try it.

Comment: @Rishi sorry , it's not working and when i clcik on the text input the alrt is appearing.

Comment: You need to work here `success: function (data) {
          consolelog(data);
        }`

Comment: If alert is coming so code is working fine till here.

Comment: i added the code and nothing happened , i don't know why it's not working but the sql and php code seems to be working fine without the preventDeafult() but like i said it's showing the first div.

Comment: Convert and echo json here  `return $filter_Result;`

Answer (score 1):

Oops! You missed a concept also ! When using ajax you need to manipulate your **DOM(Document Object Model)** by yourself on **callback functions**

You are missing **return false;** at the end of submit event. The form submit event when customized and *e.preventDefault()* is used then your implementation overrides the default behavior thus it needs to tell the form if it needs to submit the whole page or not.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {

        $('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'admin.php',
            data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            success: function () {
//filter the table using javascript code by changing the elements etc.
              alert('table is filtered');
            }
          });
    return false;
        });

    });
    </script>
```

If this not works then there must be some uncertainty like there may be some **runtime error ** which is preventing your script to propagate.

Comment: not working , what kind of run time error and where it could exist??

Comment: added some more detail please see

Comment: tried the updated code also did not work how do i manipulate DOM??